Problem in mathematical analysis

Prove that the function $f(x) = x|\sin(x)|$ gets in the interval
$(0,\infty)$ every positive value infinite times.

In other words prove that for every $0<y$ the $f(x) = y$ equation have infinite solutions in the $(0,\infty)$ interval.
I tried to prove the following statement with Intermediate value theorem and two $x$ sequence that block $y$, $f(a) \le y \le f(b)$ for each value of n and then saying something that for this reason there is a sequence $\{c_n\}$ that make $f(c_n) = y$ for every $n$. How can I prove that?

You're coming from StackOverflow, aren't you? (I recognise the backticks :-) ). Here on the Math forum you can also use dollarsigns in order to work with LaTeX-like formulae.

You can see here for information about MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/1196653

Please do not use codeblock for anything that is not actual code. It interferes with accessibility and is unnecessary.

I would approach this by splitting $f(x)$ into two separate functions:
$g(x)=x\\
h(x)=|\sin(x)|$
Since $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are both continuous in the interval $(0,\infty)$, we know that $f(x)$ (the product of two continuous functions) is also continuous on the interval.
Next, we know that the values of $g(x)$ are positive and constantly increasing to $\infty$. We also know that the values of $h(x)$ fluctuate from $0$ to $1$ and back to $0$ in the intervals $(\pi n, \pi(n+1))$, where $n$ is whole number.
Now when we take the product of both functions, the graph starts at $0$ when $x=\pi n$, covers some range of positive $y$-values, then drops back down to $0$ when $x=\pi(n+1)$. A similar trend will happen in the next interval, except now $f(x)$ will cover slightly more $y$-values since $g(x)$ is $\pi$ greater than it was in the previous cycle. Each cycle, $f(x)$ will cover more and more $y$-values before returning to $0$ since its factor $g(x)$ is always increasing. If we take $x$ to $\infty$, we'll see that $f(x)$ will have covered every $y$-value an infinite number of times in its infinite amount of cycles.

For any $T>0$, $f(x) >y$ for some $x>T$ of the form $(2n+1)\frac {\pi }2$.  Also, $f(x)=0<y$ for some $x>T$ of the form $x=n\pi$. So $f(x)=y$ for some $x>T$ and this is true for all $T$. [I am using Intermediate Value Theorem on $(T,\infty)$].
